# Автоматический "reimport" в юнити

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

У меня в ресурсах лежит файл, и кодом туда добавляеться текст, но если добавить текст, перезапустить игру и сразу же считать этот текст то добавленого текста там не будет, нужно ПКМ -> Reimport (реимпортировать) либо изменить этот файл в винде что приведет к автоматическому реимпорту, как можно выйти из этой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [AssetDatabase.Refresh()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.Refresh.html). Этот метод принудительно заставляет Unity пройтись по всем файлам, в которых были изменения и обновить их во внутренней базе. Работает только в редакторе, в игре работать не будет.